# Industrial Design Reviews

Tags: design, ux-designer, industrial-design

When a company releases a new product a lot of people are reviewing them. But their reviews are lack of theoretical information. Only mentioning about color, shape etc. and telling it is looking good or bad. Where can I find some real reviews of these designs? Let's say apple introduces airpods max and someone write an article about it how to do it better or what they did right in this product.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the site. I struggle to see how your question is related to User Experience. Reviews by magazines or users are real in that these people typically have some expertise. What more are you looking for? So please explain what you mean by "real reviews"? Also please clarify why "where can I find ..." is a user experience question and not a marketing or business question?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because (1) it's not clear what is asked, and (2) my interpretation of what is probably asked belongs to another forum.

Answer (score 0):

This is an essential part of the user review. You may need to collect Qualitative Data (User Interviews) and Quantitative Data (e.g. Data from Google Analytics).

Try asking questions that are not leading the user and asking their purpose and behavior, rather than asking do you like the color of the button.

You can start by gathering reviews from within your company as well, like other developers, QA engineers etc.